# What does "free" do in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, pascal

I found the following code snippet [here](http://angusj.com/delphi/clipper.php#code):

```
with TClipper.Create do
  try
    AddPolygon(subject, ptSubject);
    AddPolygon(clip, ptClip);
    Execute(ctIntersection, solution);
  finally
    free;
  end
```

Just curious, what does the `free` statement/function (between `finally` and `end`) do here?  Google did not help.

Comment: Beware with statements can lead to some very misleading errors.   Say that code is inside another object such as TForm1.  Which method is getting called TClipper.Free or TForm1.Free.    The with takes priority on the scope but it's common for developers to miss that and get unintended bugs.

Comment: @Robert Love: But the construct shown above is very standard.

Comment: @Andreas I would have to disagree, I see it from time to time but most of the code I look at never uses this construct, due to the problems that can rise from using it.

Comment: @Rober Love: What about `with TOpenDialog.Create do try` ...?

Comment: with creates AnonymousVariable of type TClipper
and Free is understood to be AnonymousVariable.Free;

Comment: @Andreas:  Never use it.

Comment: 'with'-statements are for developers to lazy to type....

Comment: "Never use `with`"? Surely You're Joking, Mr. Love!

Comment: Someone is too lazy to add the second "o" in "too".

Comment: "with" statements are for developers who know what they are doing and know how to use dangerous tools safely.  You can amputate a leg with a chainsaw, even your own.  If you don't know how to handle a chainsaw, don't use one.  But if you have a tree needs chopping down and you know what you are doing with one then you will get the job done far more quickly with a chainsaw than you will trying to use a safety razor.  People who say "never use with" aren't to be trusted, because they don't even trust themselves.

Comment: AFAIK the "with" statement is standardized element of Object Pascal/Delphi language, and the specification clearly states the priority of operations. Thus, I see no reason why we shouldn't use it. It's **not** a kind of trick which might stop working when upgrading compiler etc...

Comment: Andreas, I never use in the method described by this question.   with TFoo.Create do...   I have used it in plenty of other places but with care.

Comment: @migajet: It might stop when upgrading the RTL/VCL. For example if you accessed a local variable "Images" in a with statement that openes the scope for a TButton. When you upgrade to Delphi 2009 the "Images" won't reference the local variable anymore because TButton now has a "Images" property that is referenced instead.

Comment: @Andreas, definitely +99 for you :) I didn't mentioned I was referring to the construction shown in this question. I believe there's no way it might be confusing to the compiler - never ever ;)

Comment: With statements are a pain in the lower back because they *will* get abused once they have been introduced to the code. I have to maintain some legacy Borland Pascal 7 code where there are duplicate and triplicate with statements with a scope of several pages. This is a nightmare to debug.
So in order not to tempt my coworkers I will not use with statements regardless whether I think I know what I am doing or not.
(And I don't think the chainsaw example applies here. The with statement saves a few key strokes, nothing else.)

Comment: I don't use Delphi, but, as in JS, it seems prone to the same problems. The rules maybe specified but they are not simple. Unless everyone touching the code is an expert coder, there will be bugs introduced in the future. http://hallvards.blogspot.com/2004/08/with-statement-considered-harmful.html

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The code

```
with TClipper.Create do
  try
    AddPolygon(subject, ptSubject);
    AddPolygon(clip, ptClip);
    Execute(ctIntersection, solution);
  finally
    free;
  end
```

is shorthand for

```
with TClipper.Create do
begin
  try
    AddPolygon(subject, ptSubject);
    AddPolygon(clip, ptClip);
    Execute(ctIntersection, solution);
  finally
    free;
  end;
end;
```

`TClipper.Create` creates an object of type `TClipper`, and returns this, and the `with` statement, which works as in most languages, lets you access the methods and properties of this TClipper object without using the `NameOfObject.MethodOrProperty` syntax.

(A simpler example:

```
MyPoint.X := 0;
MyPoint.Y := 0;
MyPoint.Z := 0;
MyPoint.IsSet := true;
```

can be simplified to

```
with MyPoint do
begin
  X := 0;
  Y := 0;
  Z := 0;
  IsSet := true;
end;
```

)

But in your case, you never need to declare a TClipper object as a variable, because you create it and can access its methods and properties by means of the `with` construct.

So your code is almost equivelant to

```
var
  Clipper: TClipper;

Clipper := TClipper.Create;
Clipper.AddPolygon(subject, ptSubject);
Clipper.AddPolygon(clip, ptClip);
Clipper.Execute(ctIntersection, solution);
Clipper.Free;
```

The first line, `Clipper := TClipper.Create`, creates a `TClipper` object. The following three lines work with this object, and then `Clipper.Free` destroys the object, freeing RAM and possibly also CPU time and OS resources, used by the `TClipper` object.

But the above code is not good, because if an error occurrs (an exception is created) within `AddPolygon` or `Execute`, then the `Clipper.Free` will never be called, and so you have a memory leak. To prevent this, Delphi uses the `try...finally...end` construct:

```
Clipper := TClipper.Create;
try
  Clipper.AddPolygon(subject, ptSubject);
  Clipper.AddPolygon(clip, ptClip);
  Clipper.Execute(ctIntersection, solution);
finally
  Clipper.Free;
end;
```

The code between `finally` and `end` is guaranteed to run, even if an exception is created, and even if you call `Exit`, between `try` and `finally`.

What Mason means is that sometimes the `with` construct can be a paint in the ... brain, because of identifier conflicts. For instance, consider

```
MyObject.Caption := 'My test';
```

If you write this inside a `with` construct, i.e. if you write

```
with MyObect do
begin
  // A lot of code
  Caption := 'My test';
  // A lot of code
end;
```

then you might get confused. Indeed, most often `Caption :=` changes the caption of the current form, but now, due to the `with` statement, it will change the caption of MyObject instead.

Even worse, if

```
MyObject.Title := 'My test';
```

and MyObject has no `Caption` property, and you forget this (and think that the property is called `Caption`), then

```
MyObject.Caption := 'My test';
```

will not even compile, whereas

```
with MyObect do
begin
  // A lot of code
  Caption := 'My test';
  // A lot of code
end;
```

will compile just fine, but it won't do what you expect.

In addition, constructs like

```
with MyObj1, MyObj2, ..., MyObjN do
```

or nested `with` statements as in

```
with MyConverter do
  with MyOptionsDialog do
    with MyConverterExtension do
      ..
```

can produce a lot of conflicts.

## In Defence of The `With` Statement

I notice that there almost is a consensus (at least in this thread) that the `with` statement is more evil than good. Although I am aware of the potential confusion, and have fallen for it a couple of times, I cannot agree. Careful use of the `with` statement can make the code look much prettier. And this lessens the risk of confusion due to ["barfcode"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349378/new-programming-jargon-you-coined/2869527#2869527).

For example:

Compare

```
var
  verdata: TVerInfo;

verdata := GetFileVerNumbers(FileName);
result := IntToStr(verdata.vMajor) + '.' + IntToStr(verdata.vMinor) + '.' + IntToStr(verdata.vRelease) + '.' + IntToStr(verdata.vBuild);
```

with

```
with GetFileVerNumbers(FileName) do
  result := IntToStr(vMajor) + '.' + IntToStr(vMinor) + '.' + IntToStr(vRelease) + '.' + IntToStr(vBuild);
```

There is absolutely no risk of confusion, and not only do we save a temporaray variable in the last case - it also is far more readable.

Or what about this very, very, standard code:

```
with TAboutDlg.Create(self) do
  try
    ShowModal;
  finally
    Free;
  end;
```

Exactly where is the risk of confusion? From my own code I could give hundreds of more examples of `with` statements, all simplifying code.

Furthermore, as have been stated above, there is no risk of using `with` at all, as long as you know what you are doing. But what if you want to use a `with` statement together with the `MyObject` in the example above: then, inside the `with` statement, `Caption` is equal to `MyObject.Caption`. How do you change the caption of the form, then? Simple!

```
with MyObject do
begin
  Caption := 'This is the caption of MyObject.';
  Self.Caption := 'This is the caption of Form1 (say).';
end;
```

Another place where with can be useful is when working with a property or function result that takes a non-trivial amount of time to execute.

To work with the TClipper example above, suppose that you have a list of TClipper objects with a *slow* method that returns the clipper for a particular TabSheet.

Ideally you should only call this getter once, so you can either use an explicit local variable, or an implicit one using **with**.

```
var
  Clipper : TClipper;
begin
  Clipper := ClipList.GetClipperForTab(TabSheet);
  Clipper.AddPolygon(subject, ptSubject);
  Clipper.AddPolygon(clip, ptClip);
  Clipper.Execute(ctIntersection, solution);
end;
```

**OR**

```
begin
  with ClipList.GetClipperForTab(TabSheet)do
  begin
    AddPolygon(subject, ptSubject);
    AddPolygon(clip, ptClip);
    Execute(ctIntersection, solution);
  end;
end;
```

In a case like this, either method would do, but in some circumstances, typically in complex conditionals a with can be clearer.

```
var
  Clipper : TClipper;
begin
  Clipper := ClipList.GetClipperForTab(TabSheet);
  if (Clipper.X = 0) and (Clipper.Height = 0) and .... then
    Clipper.AddPolygon(subject, ptSubject);
end;
```

**OR**

```
begin
  with ClipList.GetClipperForTab(TabSheet) do
    if (X = 0) and (Height = 0) and .... then
      AddPolygon(subject, ptSubject);
end;
```

In the end is is matter of personal taste. I generally will only use a *with* with a very tight scope, and never nest them. Used this way they are a useful tool to reduce *barfcode*.

Comment: Until the IDE can figure out what "with" refers to, I will continue to avoid it.

Comment: Of course, you mean the *debugger*, not the IDE.  The IDE itself has no trouble with the meaning of with.  The compiler part of the IDE compiles "with" code perfectly accurately and Code Insight resolves references correctly.  It's only the debugger that doesn't get it right.

Comment: IMO the primary shortcoming of `with` is that it gives an excuse for placing code in the wrong place.  If the code inside the `with` statement were instead placed inside the construct for which `with` is providing an alias, all the same benefits of brevity are achieved, and the caller code looks even cleaner.

Comment: @cjrh: Well, I would say that this applies to far less than 50 % of my uses of `with`, most of which are records and it would not make any sense to add the code to the record itself.

Comment: Adding methods to records is a bundling of state and action.  It is done for exactly the same reason as for classes.  If your code segment requires manipulation of so many different fields of the record as to justify a `with` statement, I think it is reasonable to ask whether it may not be better to have the record act on itself instead, via a method call.

Comment: @cjrh: I meant that I *read* the record's members, not write to them.

Comment: In defense of the people who dislike with, I find a one letter local variable name beats a with statement for readability, maintainability, debug-ability (is that a word?), and clarity of scope.

Answer (score 15):

It's a call to TObject.Free, which is basically defined as:

```
if self <> nil then
  self.Destroy;
```

It's being executed on the unnamed TClipper object created in the `with` statement.

This is a very good example of why you shouldn't use `with`.  It tends to make the code harder to read.

Comment: This is a *very* convenient and standard construct. This way you do not need to start your procedure/unit with a large list of TOpenDialog, TMyConverter, TMyCustomDialog, TMySoundLibrary variables etc, if you just want to use a few methods somewhere.

Comment: @mjustin: I understand the possible (unforeseen) errors and the objections against the with statement, yet there are some examples where it actually improves code readability and prevents very lengthy variable statements (it would be nice if we could declare variables everywhere just like in C although language purists probably won't like that either).

Comment: The code is perfectly easy to read.  The poster didn't know what "Free" does and didn't know how "with" worked.  Eliminating the use of "with" addressed only one HALF of that understanding gap.

Comment: +1 for the answer to what does <code>free</code> do but for saying that's an example for why you shouldn't use <code>with</code> I'd give -1. the only "shouldn't" I would use is you shouldn't use tools you don't fully understand.

Answer (score 7):

Free calls the destructor of the object, and releases the memory occupied by the instance of the object.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know anything about Delphi but I would assume that it is releasing the resources used by TClipper much like a using statement in C#. That is just a guess....

Answer (score 0):

Any dinamicly created object must call **free** to free at object creation alocated memory after use. TClipper object is a desktop content creation, capture and management tool. So it is some kind of Delphi connection object with Clipper. The **create** (object creation) is handled in **try finaly end;** statment what mean, if connection with Clipper isn't successful the object TClipper will not be created and can not be freed after after of **try finaly end;** statement.

Answer (score 0):

If "with" is as evil as some posters are suggesting, could they please explain
1. why Borland created this language construct, and 
2. why they (Borland/Embarcadero/CodeGear) use it extensively in their own code? 
While I certainly understand that some Delphi programmers don't like "with", and while acknowledging that some users abuse it, I think it's silly to say "you shouldn't use it".
angusj - author of the offending code :)

Comment: Borland didn't create the language construct.  They inherited it from Wirth.  And it wasn't nearly as big of a problem before the Pascal -> Object Pascal leap, because back then the implicit `self` scoping of being inside a method didn't exist.  You can consider all methods as being wrapped in a `with self do` block, and once you have *two* implicit scope layers, you can get into some really tricky resolution issues that introduce bugs and make the code harder to fix.

Comment: Mason, I will heartily agree that "with" can, and very often is abused to the point that it's unclear or even misleading as to what the owner of certain methods/properties/variables are. However, when used in *very small* code blocks, there is no ambiguity and IMHO "with" actually improves clarity.